# How to view a file in ELF format?

Tags: file, elf, file-extension

I am a windows user, and I have an ELF (Executable and linkable file) with .out extension that contains some C code that I have to read. How can I view the contents of this file?

I have tried 'biew' and HT editor, but both fails to work properly on my system (Which is Windows 10, both those programs look severely outdated)

Please don't suggest notepad. I have tried opening in it, and most of the contents of the file did not come up properly. Also once again, I'm a windows user, and I lack access to a linux system to try the shell commands suggested in other places.

Also, I'm confused if the ELF file contains machine code(which means I have to convert it to a readable form after getting the file open) or just encrypted C code. Any help on this would be appreciated as well.

How can I view the contents of the file?

Comment: ELF is an object format (binary). It does not contain *C code* that you can read. It's also not encrypted. It's a binary format, not text of any sort. Think of it as an executable on Windows.

Comment: Okay, so how can I get it as readable C code? Maybe using some kind of decompiler?

Comment: We don't recommend software or libraries here. Google can help you with finding that information.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.